# .Net core mvc web application dependency on another

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Not saying this is a good idea, but is it technically possible to have a .net core web app depend on another? The goal is to re-use existing projects without refactoring into class libraries.

Illustrated below:

```
[Solution]
-Project1 <--- referenced web app (parent web app)
-Project2 <--- startup project (main web app)
--Dependencies
----Project1
```

This seems to compile fine, but then at runtime it throws a *AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. exception.*

This is because there are multiple controller actions with the same name from each project (for example: **public IActionResult Index()**)

Is there any way to ignore the controller actions in the parent web app? Would there be any other gotchas?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86y6S.png)

Comment: You could move the types that you'd like to share to a new class library.  Shared->Project1, Shared->Project2.

Comment: Definitely a last resort, but trying to avoid if possible.

Comment: Out of interest, why would you like to avoid that?  It's very common to put shared code in libraries that contain only what's required.  I'd argue it's much easier than trying to exclude everything you *don't* want.

Comment: Breaking shared code out of project1 means refactoring thousands of lines of code due to the new circular references that would be introduced between Shared <-> Project1.

Comment: The idea of breaking out shared code would be to maintain a dependency tree and not create any circular dependencies.  It sounds like the refactor might be a good exercise in the long run to improve maintainability.

Comment: Agreed, but I want to be sure of all my options before committing.